# How to include .NET framework redistributable in Visual Studio setup project using chaining?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, setup-project

I have a Visual Studio setup project.

My aim is to install .NET Framework 4 silently with the setup of my own application, without asking the user and without using an internet connection.

I read the "[Chaining the .NET Framework to Your Application Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee942965.aspx#chaining_redistributable)" section on MSDN, but I don't understand this approach.

Do I have to write a short batch file and put the [dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718) in the same folder as my .msi file?
Is it possible to "pack" the [dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718) into my resulting .msi file?
Where do I have to click in Visual Studio to do this?

Anyone who has experience with this? Or an idea?

Comment: Will your users be okay to install something that they have not installed without their knowledge?

Comment: If it is possible to notice them about the .NET framework, of course I'll do that. But as my application won't run without .NET framework, first it is important to me, to solve that problem.

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio Right-Click on the Setup Project and select Options.

Click button Prerequisites...

Select the second option for .Net Framework.

Rebuild!!

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to install .NET Framework 4.0 Full in many cases you can use

[.Net Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)

look at his [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc843122%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I have to use the full installation. It's a very big project with a webserver and website project included.